# How many seven digit numbers are there that are divisible by eleven?

Tags: divisibility

How many seven-digit numbers are there that are divisible by 11?

In other words, I want to find the number of seven digit numbers that are divisible by 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the last number divisible by 11 before 7 digits is 999999, so the answer is $$\left\lfloor \frac{9999999-999999}{11}\right\rfloor = 818181.$$ More generally, if $a$ is divisible by 11 and $b>a$, then the number of integers in the half open interval $(a, b]$ divisible by $11$ is given by $\left\lfloor \frac{b-a}{11} \right\rfloor$, as you can verify by trying a few small cases, and then an induction argument should follow pretty easily.

Comment: many thanks for your answer but i want the proof of the theorem or text that you write for number of 7 digit number are divisible by 11 ? please help me :(

Comment: Have you made any attempt at proving the theorem?

Comment: no i do not have any idea for proving

Comment: Try taking $a=0$ or $a=11$, and look at some small values of $b$, say $b$ up to $30$ or $40$ or so. You should see a pattern form fairly easily. Are you aware that $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ represents the floor function?

Comment: many thanks my mind was very busy because of that ... ok i know the reason .bye

Answer (score 1):

90909 * 11 is the smallest number 7 digit number divisible by 11
909090 * 11 is the largest 7 digit number divibsle by 11

So there are precisely 818181 such numbers